# how to set opacity on a button with a transparent background color programmatically

Tags: java, android

I'm working on a component library and I'm currently working on the button component, however I have a problem when it comes to the disabled button with a transparent background color, android is simply setting a gray color to the button's background color.

**here I set the color**

```
typeStyles.put("defaultBackgroundColor", context.getResources().getColor(R.color.color_transparent));
```

**here I recover the color**

```
this.mDefaultBackgroundColor = buttonType.styles.get("defaultBackgroundColor");
```

I have several types of buttons, so each button has a different configuration.

button that causing me the problem is below

[image]

the image button is a button with a disabled state and with a transparent background, the problem is that it is setting a gray color on the button.

**here I am setting the opacity.**

```
int mColor = mDefaultBackgroundColor;
byte factor = 125;
float alpha = getResources().getFloat(R.dimen.opacity_intense);
float2ByteArray(alpha);
int color = (factor << 24) | (mColor & 0x00ffffff);
disabledDrawable.setColor(color);
disabledDrawable.setStroke(mBorderWidth, mDefaultBackgroundColor);
if (!mEnabled)
    this.setAlpha(.5f);
```

Comment: The background color is defined with a selector. The disabled state is one state of them.

Comment: a button with a red background works normally, only that button with a transparent background does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I finally managed to resolve this.
I modified the lines of code below.*

```
int mColor = mDefaultBackgroundColor;
        int color = mColor;
        disabledDrawable.setColor(color);
        disabledDrawable.setStroke(mBorderWidth, mBorderColor);
        if (!mEnabled)
            this.setAlpha(.5f);
```

**before it was like this**

```
int mColor = mDefaultBackgroundColor;
byte factor = 125;
float alpha = getResources().getFloat(R.dimen.opacity_intense);
float2ByteArray(alpha);
int color = (factor << 24) | (mColor & 0x00ffffff);
disabledDrawable.setColor(color);
disabledDrawable.setStroke(mBorderWidth, mDefaultBackgroundColor);
if (!mEnabled)
   this.setAlpha(.5f);
```

**this is the result**

[expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDI3P.png)

Answer (score 0):

In the Material Components Library these is a method (it requires at least the version `1.2.0-beta01`):

```
MaterialColors.compositeARGBWithAlpha(color, alpha);
```

Otherwise you can use the [`androidx.core.graphics.ColorUtils`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/graphics/ColorUtils#setAlphaComponent(int,%20int)) class:

```
ColorUtils.setAlphaComponent(originalARGB, alpha);
```

Example:

```
int color = ColorUtils.setAlphaComponent(
           ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color....),xx);

int color = MaterialColors.compositeARGBWithAlpha(
           ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color....),xx);
```

Comment: thanks, i already managed to solve it. I posted the solution for the code below.